# Can git push accomplish this?

Tags: git

Couple of questions on git.

Currently, I'm the only user and am successfully running a few basic commands on my repository and I'm happy with the way things seem. However, I want to allow different users to manage and make changes to a repository. I've been reading things about push/pull etc. But don't understand it completely yet. Can I have suggestions as to what to read up on if I want to achieve this:

[release-directory] eg: /release/live

[developer1] eg: /developers/developer1
[developer2] eg: /developers/developer2

Say the developer works in his directory and then wants to make his version final. He needs to "push" his staging area ontol the "/release/live"? Also, what if he pushed a version that screwed things up. How can I go back? Also which branch does the content get stored in? What kinds of permissions I need to take care of to allow developer1 to push to release-directory? Both directories are on the same server, so I don't need to bother about SSH or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both directories are on the same server, so I don't need to bother about SSH or anything.

When everything is on the same server, then you need one bare repository (`git init --bare`) where every developer can push it's changes into (=is writeable by all users). Pushing into a non-bare repository is asking for trouble.

[I assume your server is running linux/bsd/macos] When your users are different unix-users you need not only to `chmod g+w` the repositoy, but also to set the sticky bit on all directories (Which means that newly created directories also inherit the permission bits, else the first user-created directory will very likely be 755, which means that no other user can create files in this directory).

> Say the developer works in his directory and then wants to make his version final. He needs to "push" his staging area ontol the "/release/live"?

The typical workflow is that the developer pushes the changes into the common repository, and afterwards these changes are transmitted into `/release/live` by a `git pull` from `/release/live`. (You can also automate this step with a hook in the common repository).

Also one can only push into a remote branch when the new branch head is a descendant of the head which lives already there. This means you can only push into a remote branch when no one else pushed something into this branch. When someone pushed into this branch, you need to pull this new branch content, and then merge or rebase your own changes with the new branch content.

> Also, what if he pushed a version that screwed things up. How can I go back?

You can always `git checkout` an older version of your project. Also there is the `git revert` command, which undos the changes of a given commit.

> Also which branch does the content get stored in?

When you start a new git repo, your changes are stored in the `master` branch. You can create a new branch with `git branch MyNewBranchName` (then you stay still at `master`) or `git checkout -b MyNewBranchName` (which also moves your working copy to the new branch). You can find out about your current branch name with `git branch` (without any arguments), then your current branch is marked with a star in front of it. When you don't need a branch anymore, you can remove it with `git branch -d MyNewBranchName` (which ensures that all commits of this branch are merged into other living branches) or `git branch -D MyNewBranchName` (this removes the branch, and commits which are not merged into other branches get eventually lost during a garbage collection run).

Also a great resource about branching is http://nvie.com/git-model.

Comment: Ah, that must have taken a while to write-up Rudi. Thanks so much! I'm going to re-read it and digest the information. I did know some of the commnands you mention though .. but nonetheless, amazing reply!

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start learning about workflows (and get more familiarity with Git in general) is the [git pro book](http://progit.org/book/) [The O'Reilly book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520123) is also great; I highly recommend.

To prevent "screwing things up," I'd recommend digging deeper, and getting more comfortable, with branching and tagging.

To prevent unwanted developers getting access to specific branches (like your 'release' branch), consider [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bryce, I'll have a read. Going to keep me occupied for a bit!